# Razor change label on HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, http-post

new to razor, I have a label and a button

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label name="Mylabel">Test + @ViewData["MyLabelUpdate"]</label>
<input type="submit" id="MyBtn"  Value="Change Label">
```

Now in the controller I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

How do I get the label to change using the actionresult method?  Thanks

Comment: You can set it in the ViewBag, right?  Put `ViewBag.Label = "whatever"` in your controller.

Comment: I tried adding this to the method
    ViewData["MyLabelUpdate"] = "My Label Update";
and then in the view I added this to the label 
+ @ViewData["MyLabelUpdate"]

Comment: ... And, did it work?  If not, please let me see your controller and view code.

Comment: didn't work, no change to the page, editted stackoverflow question to show change made

Comment: You can use ViewBag or ViewData.  I used ViewBag in the sample below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your controller look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MyLabelUpdate = "whatever";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And, your view:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label name="Mylabel">Test + @ViewBag.MyLabelUpdate</label>
<input type="submit" id="MyBtn"  Value="Change Label">
```